# How to install language in tesseract OCR

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have installed tesseract OCR and it has only 'eng' and 'osd' in the language list. I need german language. I tired following command

```
brew install tesseract-ocr-deu
```

but i am getting error.

```
Error: No available formula with the name "tesseract-ocr-deu" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
   git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Please check this: https://askubuntu.com/a/798492/810971

Answer (score 38):

On mac OS type

```
brew install tesseract-lang
```

Installs all languages, you can check them by,

```
tesseract --list-langs
```

Comment: Is it possible, to install just one specific language? Something like `brew install tesseract-deu`, which just installs the german one. Unfortunately this only gives me `These similarly named formulae were found:
tesseract ✔ tesseract-lang ✔
To install one of them, [...]
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
[...]
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: No need to install tesseract-[LANGUAGE] after installing *tesserect-lang*.  German, Spanish and many more should be available.

Answer (score 18):

For completeness, I am adding an answer on how to install and use a non-English language with Tesseract OCR on Linux. Since this is the first result I got on Google and I think it may help someone.

To install German language on Ubuntu/Debian/Linux Lite:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-deu
```

Language codes of all supported languages [can be found here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Data-Files-in-different-versions.md).

To specify the language in OCR engine use option: `-l lang`, e.g. for German:

```bash
$ tesseract -l deu 'imagename' 'stdout'
```

Answer (score 17):

With [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), this works: (tested on MacOS Mojave 10.14.3)

```
brew install tesseract-lang
```

Answer (score 9):

I had to install Italian language but tesseract-lang installation cost 164 files, 654.0MB and gives the less precise version [fast vs best](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1404) so I decided to go manual

Add path to shell (if you brew on Mac find your path with `brew info tesseract`)

```sh
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.1.0/share/tessdata/
```

Update profile (if you are on `zsh`)

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

Save the language in my case the `best` version of `ita`

```sh
wget -O $TESSDATA_PREFIX/ita.traineddata https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/ita.traineddata
```

Now you should see the added language

```sh
tesseract --list-langs
```

Comment: I had to use `export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/share/tessdata` and also had to use `brew install wget` but thanks for steering me right :)

Answer (score 4):

You download them from tesseract repository.

At the moment tessdata for 4.0 is available [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) and tessdata for 3.04 [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00).

Comment: Move to: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.3/share/tessdata/`